# How to find range diff 'datetime' and 'time'?

Tags: php

I want to find a range combining both data, that data has datetime and time data types, but datetime must ignore the time.

```
<?php
function test_duration($start_date, $end_date, $start_time, $end_time) {
    $timeInterval = '-';
    if(!empty($start_time) && !empty($end_time)) {
        $timeStart = new DateTime($start_date->format('Y-m-d').' '.$start_time->format('H:i:s'));
        $timeEnd = new DateTime($end_date->format('Y-m-d').' '.$end_time->format('H:i:s'));
        $timeInterval = $timeStart->diff($timeEnd)->format('%H:%I:%s');
    }
    return $timeInterval;
}

$start_date = '2022-09-15 01:01:01';
$end_date = '2022-09-15 02:02:02';
$start_time = '14:48:40';
$end_time = '14:48:45';

echo test_duration($start_date, $end_date, $start_time, $end_time);

?>
```

so the formula is like this:

```
range start ==> $start_date (just date) + $start_time
range end ==> $end_date (just date) + $end_time

range start - range end
```

From the code above it should produce a duration of **5** seconds.

Do you have any solution to fix my code above?

Answer (score 1):

The time can easily be removed from the date with `strstr`. Then the pure date can be combined with the new time. `strtotime` is well suited when only seconds are to be determined.

```
$start_date = '2022-09-15 01:01:01';
$end_date = '2022-09-15 02:02:02';
$start_time = '14:48:40';
$end_time = '14:48:45';

$strStart = strstr($start_date, ' ', true).' '.$start_time;
$strEnd = strstr($end_date, ' ', true).' '.$end_time;
$seconds = strtotime($strEnd) - strtotime($strStart);  // int(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Time is time, date is date, you shouldn't mix them, so let's say

```
$start_date = '2022-09-15';
$start_time = '13:00:00';
$end_date = '2022-09-15';
$end_time = '14:00:00';

print strtotime($end_date) + strtotime($end_time) - strtotime($start_date) - strtotime($start_time);
```

You'll get 3600 seconds

Answer (score 0):

If you know the date is in a fixed format can't you just explode the string on the central space like this?

```
<?php
function test_duration($start_date, $end_date, $start_time, $end_time) {
    $timeInterval = '-';
    if(!empty($start_time) && !empty($end_time)) {
        $startDateOnly=explode(' ',$start_date)[0];
        $endDateOnly=explode(' ', $end_date)[0];
        $timeStart = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d H:i:s', $startDateOnly." ".$start_time);
        $timeEnd = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d H:i:s', $endDateOnly." ".$end_time);
        $timeInterval = $timeStart->diff($timeEnd)->format('%h:%i:%s');
    }
    return $timeInterval;
}

$start_date = '2022-09-15 01:01:01';
$end_date = '2022-09-15 02:02:02';
$start_time = '14:48:40';
$end_time = '14:48:45';

echo test_duration($start_date, $end_date, $start_time, $end_time);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your start is quite good, the use of `DateTime` class is one of the ways to solve your issue. The idea here can be illustrated as follows:

- create a `DateTime` object from the starting date and then alter its time (hours, minutes and seconds) based on the starting time you supply.
- do the same thing as the first step but for the ending date so we'll create a `DateTime` object from the ending date and then alter its time based on the ending time.
- return the difference between the two dates in seconds:

  - to do so we will get the timestamps from both dates
  - make a simple subtraction of th two timestamps
  - return the result. We may return the absolute value here to always get a positive number for the case when the starting date is greater than the ending date (not required but that can be seen as an improvement).

Here's a [live demo](https://3v4l.org/2Cl6k#v7.4.21) too

```
$startDate = '2022-09-15 01:01:01';
$endDate = '2022-09-15 02:02:02';
$startTime = '14:48:40';
$endTime = '14:48:45';

function diffInSeconds($startDate, $endDate, $startTime, $endTime)
{
    // create a DateTime object based on $startingDate and then alter the time to use the $startingTime instead
    $startDate = (new DateTime($startDate))->setTime(
        ($startTime = explode(':', $startTime))[0],
        $startTime[1],
        $startTime[2]
    );

    // create a DateTime object based on $endingDate and then alter the time to use the $endingTime instead
    $endDate = (new DateTime($endDate))->setTime(
        ($endTime = explode(':', $endTime))[0],
        $endTime[1],
        $endTime[2]
    );

    // return the difference in seconds which will always be positive thanks to the "abs" function
    return abs($endDate->getTimestamp() - $startDate->getTimestamp());
}

// run...
echo diffInSeconds($startDate, $endDate, $startTime, $endTime); // prints: 5
```

> the above is code somehow primitive, it doesn't have any checks on whether the date/times are correct or not also it expects the times to be in the following format "HH:MM:SS".

> Anyway, i strongly recommend looking at more modern utilities, especially the [`Carbon`](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) library which makes working with dates and times in `PHP` a piece of cake.

> Learn more about [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects on php.net.